# Should I store the choices and vote count for my poll app into an array or a map

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Hello, happy new year** !

I am currently thinking about making a simple poll app but I am not sure on how to store the choices and the vote count.

Basically I have :

- string : question
- string: uid
- etc
- And here are the choices
- And here the vote count

I was thinking about putting the choices and the count **into an array**

- choices : ["yes", "no"]
- votes : [0, 24]

So the choice "yes" has the index 0, it has 0 vote, the choice "no" has the index 1, it has 24 votes, it does work well but when it comes to firestore security rules (if I understood correctly), I can check if there is always 2 items into the array, but I can't check the value of each item, so the user could change it for [35, 0] instead of let's say [1, 24].

**The other idea** was to store it **into a map**

- choices : {x0: "yes", x1: "no"}
- votes: {x0: 0, x1: 24}

I assume the user could only modify a specific field, and I may be able to prevent the user from replacing the value by whatever he wants, but, I didn't find out how to let the user update a dynamic field (as I don't know which x[i] he is going to modify, and I don't know the amount of x[i])

So if you guys have any ideas or suggestions I will be pleased to hear them !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can check the individual contents of the array**, if you also check the size of the array first.  Arrays will show up as a List type object in security rules.  If you assert that the size of the List is 2, then you can also use the usual array indexing operation to check values at indexes 0 and 1.  This is all very clear in the [API documentation for List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List).

What you can't do with a List is iterate the values, which is not the case here.